# Can't create new folder from a FolderBrowserDialog via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

In my powershell script I open a `FolderBrowserDialog` to get a path from User. I'd like to allow User to create new folder but I get this message regardless of folder selected.

> [Window Title] Invalid location
>
> [Content] You can't create a new folder here. Choose a different
>   location.

[image: Example error dialog window]

I thought maybe I need to elevate the execution policy on PowerShell, but that didn't make a difference.

```
# [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$FBD = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$FBD.ShowNewFolderButton = $True
$FBD.RootFolder = "MyComputer"
$FBD.SelectedPath = "C:\"
$FBD.Description = "Navigate and select directory"
$Choice = $FBD.ShowDialog()
if ($Choice -eq "OK")
{
    Write-Host "Selected Path: " $FBD.SelectedPath
}
```

---

**UPDATE** Additional info:

- I can manually create folder inside explorer
- I can create folder within powershell with 'New-Item', **without** elevated privilege

Things I've tried without success:

- Running terminal with elevated privileges
- Using Python TKinter filedialog (same issue)?!

All in all it seems like a Windows permission issue with calling Windows Forms.

Comment: Does the user running the form actually have access to create new folders in `C:` (or wherever you navigate to)?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: The user is able to create folder manually and inside powershell with 'New-Item'. Do forms have their own permissions?

Comment: No, that's not the issue then. Does this happen everywhere in the folder hierarchy, or in a specific place?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be limited to a specific location. I tried multiple hierarchies with same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have admin rights to the location or you're trying to access a restricted area that you need to run the script in an elevated PowerShell terminal. No need to call c# when you can do it much simpler.

```
 New-Item -Path "c:\" -Name "NameOfFolder" -ItemType Directory
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm able to create directory using "New-Item" without elevated privileges. I'm calling C# so that users can navigate and select path, instead of typing it. But I agree that it seems like a permission issue, however running elevated PowerShell terminal still gives me the same issue.

Comment: So the .ShowDialog() Will not work unless it's in the ISE or you call the Windows.Form class. It becomes a pain but if you're okay with that then try: [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.windows.forms”) in the very top of your script.

Comment: One other thing. Get-ExecutionPolicy - See what your policy is set to. It sound more like you have an issue with the directory where you're executing from?

Comment: I'd tried calling the Windows.Form before without any success (commented out first line). I've set the policy to Bypass with no success. But running it in ISE worked! I'd like to run it without ISE though.

Comment: Do you have restrictions based by GPO that prevent some users from getting to certain areas of the computer? Hiding the c: drive for instance?

Comment: also, try running the scrip from the desktop of where you're trying to execute the script.

Comment: There are GPO restrictions, but I'll have to check with IT tomorrow on the specifics. No luck running from Desktop. It seems if the Form is coming from a not "trusted" app it won't let me make new folder.

Comment: AppLocker may be introduced into your org

Comment: Marking this as the solution, since the issue is related to GPO restrictions. I'm fighting IT to get some clarification.Will update if I come across a workaround.